# How To Evenly Space Tabs Across the Whole Tab Bar

Tags: reactjs, tabs, antd

I don't see anything related to this is the documentation, does anyone know how this can be achieved? I noticed ant design uses rc-tabs, so I looked at their documentation but didn't notice anything either, thought maybe I didn't look hard enough. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding the following `.ant-tabs` less rules fixes this issue for me:

```
.ant-tabs {
  &-nav {
    display: flex;

    .ant-tabs-tab {
      flex-grow: 1;
      margin-right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

So long as the tab bar has enough width for each tab and its title, this will evenly space out all of the tabs while also eliminating the empty space between each tab.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: How did you override ant design less?

Comment: I know it's an old comment but you can wrap the whole thing in a div with a classname and then set the styles OP said inside this class in the css, overrides the specificity and works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply css like this

```
.ant-tabs-nav-list .ant-tabs-tab {
  width: 120px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background: #5a56e9 !important;
}
```