# How to spread tab items evenly?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm developing new administration page. On that registration page I need to have a menu with five tabs for each administration section. We are using ant for angular and for tab menu we are using component from ant library.

I have tried to override style for ant tabs as described here:

[How To Evenly Space Tabs Across the Whole Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118124/how-to-evenly-space-tabs-across-the-whole-tab-bar)

and here

https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/2242

None of those articles helped.

Here is code example

```
    <nz-tab nzTitle="LAN STATUS">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </nz-tab>
    <nz-tab nzTitle="DHCP">
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </nz-tab>
    <nz-tab nzTitle="DNS">
        Content of Tab Pane 2
      </nz-tab>
      <nz-tab nzTitle="USERS">
          Content of Tab Pane 2
      </nz-tab>
      <nz-tab nzTitle="AMAZON SERVICES">
          Content of Tab Pane 2
      </nz-tab>
  </nz-tabset>
```

I would like to have a evenly spaced  element inside

Comment: Hi guys, changing to something other than css is not an option. I have existing styles from older version of application which must be reused on new platform. I have transpiled given scss code fragment into css and added it to the component css files like so. 

```:host ::ng-deep .ant-tabs-nav {
    display: flex !important;
  }
  
:host ::ng-deep .ant-tabs-nav .ant-tabs-tab {
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }```

tabs are bigger but they don't take whole container space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular have encapsulation components so you should use deep or disable that encapsulation (I prefer use deep).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'second-cmp',
  template: `<div class="cmp">Second Component</div>`,
  styles: ['.cmp { border: green 2px solid; }'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  // Use to disable CSS Encapsulation for this component
})
```

or

```
:host ::ng-deep nz-tab X{
    color: red;
}
```

You can read more here https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted in your link solves your problem. You just to add this scss to your project:

```
.ant-tabs {
  &-nav {
    display: flex;

    .ant-tabs-tab {
      flex-grow: 1;
      margin-right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

(make sure you are really using *.scss in your angular project, default is *.css)

You then have two places to add it:

1. **In the global stylesheet.** Your project comes with a `style.scss` file. just add the snippet there and all your tabs will be evenly divide
2. **Inside your component styles.** The same styles, but because of angular view encapsulation, your scss starts like this: `:host ::ng-deep .ant-tabs {`. (you can finde a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-zmmkth). You can also disable the view encapsulation on your component with:

   @Component({ 
   ...
     encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   })